# Cambiar data de un ajax cuando pulso un boton? Como le hago?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$**(document).ready(function(){  
    $.ajax({
        data: {'piso': numeroPiso},
        url: "./php/btraerbodega.php",
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response) {
            pisos = JSON.parse(response);
            cargarPlano('piso' + numeroPiso, '.png',pisos);
            $('.piso').click(function(e){                     
                numeroPiso = e.currentTarget.innerHTML;
                cargarPlano('piso' + numeroPiso, '.png',pisos);
            });**
```

Como hago para que la variable numeroPiso que hasta el momento es estatica, la cambie por el click function que ya vendria siendo por e.currentTarget.innerHTML; para que cargue otra imagen del piso segun haya pulsado el boton?

Answer (score 0):

Crea la variable numeroPiso como variable global con el valor predeterminado que quieras que tenga cuando se inicie el doucment.ready.

A parte crea un método que cuando haces click en el botón cambie el valor de la variable numeroPiso y posteriormente haces la petición Ajax.